# Using 2 datsets in SSRS Axapta 2012

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In 2012 dimensions could be multiple(dynamic) for any employee.

Along with Employee details i need to show the dimensions. Now, I have a dataset in ssrs with empl details and another dataset with dimensions(multiple).

How can i show it together e.g
Name: XYZ
dimension1
dimension2
dimension3

Name:ABC
dimension1
dimension2
.
.
.

Thanks in advance
Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you can do this from a sub-report or by using the [LookUp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

Please take a look at the following on Stack Overflow: [Using Fields in Multiple Datasets in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342896/using-fields-in-multiple-datasets-in-ssrs)

It seems like the LookUp() function what you are looking for. Here is [a good article](http://blog.jontav.com/post/23229005764/ssrs-lookup) on  using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single table for both emp details and dimensions. Create separate field for each dimension types. And fill them with values. then display them on the ssrs table.

Hope this helps.