# SSRS / BIDS - Comparing Fields in Multiple Datasets to get a Third Value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, bids, reportbuilder

I am using BIDS 2008 to create SSRS reports.

I have two data sets (one is manually created, one from SQL Server) and I'm trying to retrieve a third value from one data set, where it to other fields match.

I've been trying to use a IIF statement but have had no luck.

Example below;

```
=IIF(Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset1" = Fields!Name.Value, "Dataset2",Fields!Age.Value, "Dataset2,"")
```

Hopefully someone can help, I'm rather stuck right now...

Comment: You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342896/using-fields-in-multiple-datasets-in-ssrs.

Comment: Is your SSRS instance running 2008 or 2008 R2?  If you're using R2, you can use the Lookup() or Lookupset() functions to retrieve data from other datasets based on lookup keys.

Comment: I believe its running R2, what would be the format of using the Lookup() or Lookupset() function?

Answer (score 0):

You want LookUp() by the looks of things. LookUp() matches data across datasets where there is a 1-1 relationship, like in the case of your Name fields matching...

=LookUp(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Age.Value, "Dataset2")

Comment: This looks fantastic, however I am getting an "Unknown Collection Member" on the second Fields!Name.Value. How do I tell BIDS that the second Fields!Name.Value is from a different Dataset than the first?

Comment: The 4th Parameter in LookUp() does that. The assumption is the Tablix in the report that you're putting the expression in is linked to "DataSet1", so the first parameter referring to Fields!Name.Value is assumed to be from that dataset. The second Fields!Name.Value and the Fields!Age.Value are specified as being in "Dataset2" as part of the LookUp() function.

Make sure that the Tablix is bound to "Dataset1" by going to Tablix Properties and in the Dataset name field selecting "DataSet1"